# Mahout K-means has different behavior based on the number of mapping tasks

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I experience a strange situation when running Mahout K-means:
Using the a pre-selected set of initial centroids, I run K-means on a SequenceFile generated by lucene.vector. The run is for testing purposes, so the file is small (around 10MB~10000 vectors).

When K-means is executed with a single mapper (the default considering the Hadoop split size which in my cluster is 128MB), it reaches a given clustering result in 2 iterations (Case A).
However, I wanted to test if there would be any improvement/deterioration in the algorithm's execution speed by firing more mapping tasks (the Hadoop cluster has in total 6 nodes). 
I therefore set the -Dmapred.max.split.size parameter to 5242880 bytes, in order to make mahout fire 2 mapping tasks (Case B). 
I indeed succeeded in starting two mappers, but the strange thing was that the job finished after 5 iterations instead of 2, and that even at the first assignment of points to clusters, the mappers made different choices compared to the single-map execution . What I mean is that after close inspection of the clusterDump for the first iteration for both two cases, I found that in case B some points were not assigned to their closest cluster.

Could this behavior be justified by the existing K-means Mahout implementation?

Comment: Can you verify it really uses (all) the cluster centers? Does running cases A and B multiple times yield different results each run?

Comment: Case A gives the same results but case B produces results with small differences in different runnings..

Comment: Interesting. Did you look at the Mahout kmeans code yet? K-means is really simple, it should be just a few lines.

Comment: I ve post the question in the mahout list (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201209.mbox/<506427A5.2090001@csd.auth.gr>) .As you can see there is probably a problem in the reduce phase, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the sources, I see two problems with the Mahout k-means implementation.

First of all, the way the S0, S1, S2 statistics are kept is probably not numerically stable for large data sets. Oh, and since k-means actually does not even use S2, it is also unnecessary slow. I bet a good implementation can beat this version of k-means by a factor of 2-5 at least.

For small data sets split onto multiple machines, there seems to be an error in the way they compute their means. Ouch. This will amplify if the reducer is applied to more than one input, in particular when the partitions are small. To be more verbose, the cluster mean apparently is initialized with the previous mean instead of the 0 vector. Now if you if you reduce 't' copies of it, the resulting vector will be off by 't' times the previous mean.

Initialization of `AbstractCluster`:

```
setS1(center.like());
```

Update of the mean:

```
getS1().assign(x, Functions.PLUS);
```

Merge of multiple copies of a cluster:

```
setS1(getS1().plus(cl.getS1()));
```

Finalization to new center:

```
setCenter(getS1().divide(getS0()));
```

So with this approach, the center will be offset from the proper value by the previous center times `t / n` where `t` is the number of splits, and `n` the number of objects.

To fix the numerical instability (which arises whenever the data set is not centered on the 0 vector), I recommend replacing the S1 statistic by the true mean, not S0*mean. Both S1 and S2 can be incrementally updated at little cost using the incremental mean formula which AFAICT was used in the original "k-means" publication by MacQueen (which actually is an online kmeans, while this is Lloyd style batch iterations). Well, for an incremental k-means you obviously need the updatable mean vector anyway... I believe the formula was also discussed by Knuth in his essential books. I'm surprised that Mahout does not seem to use it. It's fairly cheap (just a few CPU instructions more, no additional data, so it all happens in the CPU cache line) and gives you extra precision when you are dealing with large data sets.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Although there are some parts that are not clear to me. 1st: what do you mean by saying "the data set is not centered on the 0 vector".2nd: why do you say that the problem occurs for small datasets? Do you think that for bigger datasets this wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: For really big data sets, `t/n` should hopefully become small again. If the data set is centered around 0, the errors should not escalate as much, I guess. Still, computing "S1 / S0" probably loses numerical precision.